# How to include head into snscountplot

Tags: jupyter-notebook, seaborn

How do I include head into snscountplot. Right now the graph shows everything I want to limit it to 10 but when I used the code below I get an error.

```
cp=sns.countplot(x='Publisher', data=df, order=df['Publisher'].value_counts().index.head(10))
plt.xticks(rotation=60)
```

[image]

Comment: So, which error messages did you get? How did you try to solve it?

Comment: Did you try `order=df[...].value_counts().index[:10]`?

Comment: @JohanC, i tried it but it does not work too

Comment: When you write "it doesn't work", it would really help if you explained what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: You added the error message for wrongly using `head()` onto an index. `head()` only works for dataframes.  Why didn't you try `sns.countplot(x='Publisher', data=df, order=df['Publisher'].value_counts().index[:10])`?  Note that on StackOverflow, you are supposed to add the full error trace as text, not as image.  In this case, the error message is quite straight forward, so you should try an alternative way to solve.

Comment: My apologies, it was a syntax error. It works now. Thank you so much @JohanC